# Reverse Data binding android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-databinding

```
<EditText
    android:text="@={signUpViewModel.name}"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:id="@+id/signUpName"/>
```

this is my view model

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
       var name: String? = null

       fun setNameToUi(newName: String?){
            name = newName
       }   
}
```

can I use the setNameToUi to perform the reverse binding

Comment: did you check the documentation? 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way

Comment: here i am extending the class to ViewModel()

Comment: What do you mean reverse binding? . 1st you getting name from UI now you want to set name to UI is that it ?

Comment: solved the issue by using MutableLiveData<String> instead of String

Answer (score -1):

You should using live Data instead of String as in the following example:

```
var name: String? = null
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: by using MutableLiveData<String> instead of String